# Discord.py dmall command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, command, bots

I was making a dmall command and for the ctx.members it says `unexpected intended block`. 
How do i fix this

```py
@bot.command()
async def dmall(ctx, *, message):
```

**Get the list of all members in the server**

```py
members =ctx.guild.members
```

**Loop through each member and send a DM**

```py
for member in members:

try:
    await member.send(message)
    print(f"Sent a DM to {member.name}
    #{member.discriminator}")

except:
    print(f"Failed to send a DM to
    {member.name}#{member.discriminator}")
    await ctx. send("DMs sent to all members!")
```

Answer (score 0):

The print statements cannot be split into 2 lines like that.

```
print(f"Failed to send a DM to {member.name}#{member.discriminator}")
```

Alternatively, you can also use `\` (backslash` to tell python to continue reading from the next line.

```
print(f"Failed to send a DM to \
{member.name}#{member.discriminator}")
```

Because the code in the original question is poorly formatted and if that's not the issue. Check the indentation of each line. After defining functions, you should indent.

```
def myfunction(): 
    pass
```

After a statement like `try, except` (or basically after a colon `:`), another indent.

```
def myfunction():
    try:
        print(int("abc"))
    except ValueError:
        print(123)
```